# Error 1004 en tiempo de ejecución al pegar valores en excel

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Se ha producido el error '1004' en tiempo de ejecución: 
>   Error en el método PasteSpecial de la clase Range

Tengo una hoja excel en la cuál he sobrescrito el funcionamiento de la combinación CTRL+V.

En la hoja ThisWorkBook tengo:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "^{v}", "FormatoCeldas"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Desactivate()
    Application.OnKey "^{v}", ""
End Sub
```

El procedimiento FormatoCeldas hace lo siguiente:

```
Public Sub FormatoCeldas()
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Cuando copio el valor de una celda y lo pego en otra, funciona todo bien.

Pero cuando copio valores de cualquier sitio que no sea Excel, por ejemplo Bloc de Notas, y lo intento pegar en una celda Excel con Ctrl + V, me da el error arriba mencionado.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando haces pegado especial desde una fuente que no es Excel, no tienes disponible la opción "Pegar valores". Puedes hacer la prueba copiando algún texto desde el bloc de notas e intentando hacer pegado especial en Excel manualmente.

Comment: Gracias lo acabo de comprobar y sólo tengo la opción de "Mantener solo Texto". Hay alguna función que emule esa opción?

Comment: Esto parece que hace lo que dices: `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Texto"`

Comment: No funciona tampoco, esa línea de código da el siguiente error: Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto.

Comment: Eso me lo da a mí también si pongo `**Selection**.PasteSpecial`, sin embargo con `**ActiveSheet**.PasteSpecial` funciona

Comment: Correcto, con ActiveSheet funciona pero sólo cuando se pegan valores copiados de sources diferentes a excel, pero cuando el origen de los datos es otra celda de excel no funciona y salta error.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución temporal que he implementado, sería capturar el error que se produce cuando no está disponible la opción "Pegar valores", y hacer un simple pegado, puesto que en ese caso sólo estaría disponible la opción de pegar "Mantener solo texto" y se mantendría el formato de destino.

```
    On Error GoTo CopiedFromOutside

        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub

CopiedFromOutside:

    Selection.PasteSpecial
```

Comment: El problema con este enfoque es que copia formato (negritas, colores, etc)

Comment: Estoy probando a copiar de diferentes fuentes de origen (word, SublimeText, UltraEdit, Teradata) con diferentes formatos y en todos los casos al pegar en el Excel  de destino me lo pega sin formato. Trabajo con Office 2010